# How can I stop Xbox 360 from updating when there haven't actually been updates?

Tags: xbox-360

If I happen to put in an Xbox-360 game that I haven't played for over 2 weeks or so, I always get an update to the game. It disconnects me from live and restarts (Which I despise because it never reconnects to my group chat after).

I have played at LAN parties and my Xbox seems to be the only one in the group updating the games. I update games so frequently that it's getting on my nerves and I know these game developers are not releasing new updates as frequent as I'm updating. Is there a memory cache deletion option I need to change in the Xbox settings?

Comment: What games? I see the same behavior, but only once typically then it's done.

Comment: It happens to almost all my games. I mainly own top Blockbuster games. It happens after about 2 weeks of inactivity.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried [clearing the system cache](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971755)? You may have a corrupt update that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The XBOX 360 only keep the last 5 game updates in it's Cache.  So if you haven't played a game in a while or have played 5 games before, you will get an update for more than likely.

Comment: Do you have a source of information about this?

Comment: I stand to be corrected, but I believe it changes depending on the console model. Old Core models had less internal flash whereas the newer post-NXE Arcade consoles came with extra flash memory. The new Xbox 360 S Arcade (S for Slim BTW) has 4GB of internal storage. If the console has a hard drive I think the situation changes once more and its also dependant on the size of the title updates.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Tricky, I don't think this is much of an answer, but screw it, here it is anyway. As I said, I cleared my system cache, and was immediately presented with a new update for a game that definitely didn't actually need one. Since then, though, updates have become less and less frequent, until finally, it seems that the only games and applications that update now are the ones that definitely DO need it, like games that I haven't played on my system yet, or updates to applications like Netflix and ESPN. If your problem is still persisting after the system cache has been cleared, just let me know, and I'll try to think of what else I may have done differently, because whatever was done differently, it made my Xbox stop hating me. lol

Comment: This effectively duplicates @HenryHey's answer.